# Access ES6 type with same name as imported type

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, ecmascript-6

I have a Typescript class in which I import some Map module:

```
import { Map, MapboxOptions, MapDataEvent, MapMouseEvent } from "mapbox-gl";
```

Late in the code I have a function that uses ES6's **Map** object. It give's me a compilation error:

```
type Map is not generic
```

and this is because it is trying to use Mapbox Map instead of ES6 Map.

I know that I can rename Mapbox's Map name so I just have one Map name per class but I am wondering: Is it posible to access ES6 Map type without renaming the Mapbox one?

Comment: You can use `global.Map`, assuming you haven't assigned the Mapbox Map to the global scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it posible to access ES6 Map type without renaming the Mapbox one?

Not recommended. Rename local variables (in your case the import) if you want to use a global of the same name.

## Hack

Use `global.Map` but again, not recommended. A simpler solution is to rename the import.

Comment: Oh! Perfect. That makes sense: there is no way to know if `global` was redefined elsewhere. Thank you!